# Multiple API Request in getInitialProps and getServerSideProps slow Down the performance - Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Please help to fix this issue

I am building a dynamic website for displaying live match scores and stats everything is fine.

Before deploying on the server we test the performance and stress test on our staging environment.

**The Mobile score is 50** and **the Desktop score is 80** on the performance test.
Lighthouse reporting the **google tag manager** and **DFP** takes time to execute and Initial server response time takes time

My question is how to reduce server initial response time and Javascript execution time. How I improve performance
Below are details what I did in the code

1. How to load third-party scripts without blocking time like **Google Tag Manager** and **DFP scripts**. I have added **GA** code on **_document.js** and for DFP using **react-dfp** package
   but it's slow down the performance
2. **header**, **header2** and **Right bar** and **post list** components should **Refresh** after the 1-Min of interval for that I am using **useEffect()** hook
3. Fetching **Header, Footer, Rightbar, LeftBar** component data from API inside the **getInitialProps** with the help of **Axios**. These components are common for all the pages
4. Fetching slider and post list Component data inside **getServerSideProps** with the help of **Axios** package

**Header, Header 2, Left, Right, Footer**

Above component imported using `dynamic () import` function with `ssr:false`

Imported below component normally

**Slider**, **Post list**

Below the sample code.

```
 ********** _app.js **********

 MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {    
       const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
       const header = await axios(header_api)
       const header2 = await axios(header2_api)   
       const left = await axios(left_api)
       const right = await axios(right_api)
       const footer = await axios(footer_api)
    
       return {        
           appProps:{
               header,
               header2,
               left,
               right,
               footer
           } 
        }
     }
```

```
    ************* Home.js ***********
    export async function getServerSideProps(context){    
       const slider = await axios(slider_api)
       const postlist = await axios(postlist_api)    
       return {
          props :{ 
                  slider,
                  postlist
          }    
     }
```

```
*********** _document.js ***************
class MyDocument extends Document {  
  
  render() {
    console.log('__document.js');    
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
      <Head>        
                ******* other third party scripts *** 
                <script async dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XXXXXXXXX');`}}/>
      </Head>
      <body id="body-wrap">
      <noscript dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=XXXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`}}></noscript>
        <Main />        
        <NextScript />        
      </body>            
    </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @Cully read my question again I have ask how to reduce server initial response time and javascript execution time I have tried everything that is available on google if you have any article or blog please share with me

Comment: I see that you edited your post to include your question. That's helpful, good improvement 

Comment: I'm just trying to help you improve your post so you might get an answer.

Comment: That's a lot of questions, you may get more answers if you focus the question on a single issue instead. But regarding the server initial response time, you could start by making all those requests in parallel (with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for example) rather than one after the other.